# Python package namespace prefix without creating blank directories

Tags: python, namespaces, packaging

I maintain a Python library that is packaged so that the namespace prefix `mycompany.mydivision.productx`

To achieve this, our source code is stored in directory structure `mycompany/mydivision/productx` but really the first two directories don't do anything except to create the desired namespace.

Is there an alternate way to get namespace prefixes rather than to create these empty parent directories?
We have a lot of legacy code that imports based on this namespace.

We support both Python 2.7 and Python 3 but are migrating to 3 so a Python 3 only solution is fine.